# Facebook og:description with dynamically php variable

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-opengraph

I have simple mail registration process on my site. When user fill the form, system sending verify email and move form data to temp_table. When user click confirm in email data are moved to original_table and second email is sending. What I want to do is add one variable to my og:description tag. Below is my code

```
<?php $passkey=$_GET['passkey'];
$tbl_name1="temp";

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($result){
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1){
        $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $name=$rows['name'];
}
?>

<meta property="og:description" content="My sample description with variable - <?php echo $name; ?>" />
```

but it doesn't take te variable. My sample link is

```
example.com/confirm?passkey=eb35700460247fe469efd524a6a276e4
```

so based on passkey I can get my name form database. Question is, how to pass this name value to my og tag? Facebook debuger don't throw any errors.

Comment: is the og:url different? there can only be one set of og tags for one og:url. if the og tags for one url change, you have to re-scrape it.

Comment: @luschn base url is example.com/confirm, now every user have own individual url. So when I send email to you, you have
example.com/confirm?passkey=111111111111
when I send it to somebody else, he got example.com/confirm?passkey=e9129sd91d91 etc. And every passcode is connected to other value in database.